How to Add New Contacts to a Journey in SFMC Immediately When They Appear in a Data Cloud Segment?
I have a journey in Journey Builder in SFMC which is triggered by automation.
The automation do some validation in SQL query with the segment from DC which is activated in a shared data extension (default behavior in integration between SFMC and DC). I want to ensure that contacts who appear in a segment (data in a shared Data Extension) in SFMC are added to the journey immediately as they appear, without waiting for the run.
What would be the most optimal method to achieve this? Should I continue starting the automation every hour? Are there other best practices for such a setup? If I didn't hav to do this validation would it be possible to do with an hourly journey schedule with the  shared data extension (segment from DC) as an entry or maybe it's not an optimal way?
Thanks for your help!


"Data Extension" based Journeys, no matter the source - will not run immediately when a row gets created. (=event-based).

They will run on a schedule (=time-based) which can be a clock you set, or inherited from an automation that triggers the journey. E.g. hourly, even if no records were created.


Unlike Sales Cloud (SFSC), which has "track that a record was created" mechanics that can e.g. trigger a flow - Marketing Cloud (SFMC) does not have an "event" like "added to data extension" that it could react upon.
Meaning, to achieve what you state - immediate reaction to inject ONE records into journey asap - Marketing Cloud needs an API call per record and an "API Event" as Entry source in the journey. The API call constitutes the "event" that Marketing Cloud's can react to immediately.
"Sales Cloud Entry Events" from MC Connect essentially just work because they combine both things. Use the SFSC side to react on an event SFSC tracks, inform SFMC via API to run immediately.

Ok, thank you for this answer. So you don't see any way to configure Data Cloud and SFMC to make immediate update once someone joined the segment, right?

I am not excluding the option as I don't  know all Data Cloud configuration options.
I am saying IF the SFMC-side processing starts with a Data Extension, SFMC technically cannot react on that as it does not "listen" to record creations in DEs. If however, instead you trigger API Events, any system - Data Cloud or not - could very well trigger real-time reactions in SFMC;
